# NullReferenceException при попытке работы с массивом

Tags: c#, массивы

При попытке работы с массивом OnlyGreatMarks в последнем методе происходит ошибка:

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Причем одна и та же ошибка появляется в двух разных местах (отмечены комментарием).

Данный метод должен вернуть ступенчатый массив со значениями из двумерного массива, которые больше 8.

Вот сам код:

```
class Matrix
{
    private int[,] matr;
    static private Random rand = new Random();

    public Matrix(int[,] matr)
    {
        this.matr = matr;
    }

    public Matrix()
    {
        matr = new int[30,10];
        for (int i = 0; i < matr.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < matr.GetLength(1); j++)
                matr[i, j] = rand.Next(1,10);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < matr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                result += $"{matr[i,j]}\t";
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;    
    }

    public void GreatMarksOnly()
    {
        int[] OnlyGreatMarks = new int[0]; 
        int[][] MatrixWithGreatMarks = new int[0][];
        for (int i = 0; i < matr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (matr[i, j] > 8)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref OnlyGreatMarks, OnlyGreatMarks.Length + 1);//первый NullReferenceException
                    OnlyGreatMarks[OnlyGreatMarks.Length - 1] = matr[i, j];
                }
            }
            if (OnlyGreatMarks.Length > 0)//второй NullReferenceException
            {
                Array.Resize(ref MatrixWithGreatMarks, MatrixWithGreatMarks.Length + 1); 
                MatrixWithGreatMarks[MatrixWithGreatMarks.Length - 1] = OnlyGreatMarks;
                OnlyGreatMarks = null;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixWithGreatMarks.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MatrixWithGreatMarks[i].Length; j++)
                Console.Write($"{MatrixWithGreatMarks[i][j]}\t");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Напишите в вопросе: (1) что должен делать этот код (2) зачем нужно `OnlyGreatMarks = null;` (3) каким образом ошибка появляется в двух местах, насколько я понимаю после первой программа метод прекращает работу.

Comment: Согласен с @defaultlocale, проблема явно в присвоении null массиву и последующими попытками вывести Length у null. Может попробуйте заменить присвоение null, на присвоение new int[0].

Comment: @Oleksii Potapov Заменил null на new int[0] и все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void ExtendArray<T>(ref T[] array, T new_value)
{
    if (array != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
        array[array.Length - 1] = new_value;
    }
    else
    {
        array = new T[] { new_value };
    }
}

public void GreatMarksOnly()
{
        int[] OnlyGreatMarks = new int[0];
        int _size = OnlyGreatMarks.Length;
        int[][] MatrixWithGreatMarks = new int[0][];

        for (int i = 0; i < matr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (matr[i, j] > 8)
                {
                    //Array.Resize(ref OnlyGreatMarks, OnlyGreatMarks.Length + 1);//первый NullReferenceException
                    _size = OnlyGreatMarks.Length;
                    ExtendArray(ref OnlyGreatMarks, _size + 1);
                    _size = OnlyGreatMarks.Length;
                    OnlyGreatMarks[_size - 1] = matr[i, j];
                }
            }
            _size = OnlyGreatMarks.Length;
            if (_size > 0)//второй NullReferenceException
            {
                Array.Resize(ref MatrixWithGreatMarks, MatrixWithGreatMarks.Length + 1);
                MatrixWithGreatMarks[MatrixWithGreatMarks.Length - 1] = OnlyGreatMarks;
                OnlyGreatMarks = null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Кидает ту же ошибку

Comment: Чушь какая-то, если Array. Resize получит null по ссылке, то он создаст новый массив.